# New features that are added in c++11 that existed in boost

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

What are all the new features that are added in c++11 that existed in boost?

I'm using boost in my project from long time. I want to reduce dependency on boost in new modules which I'm writing if those features existed in c++11.

Comment: You can simply look at the C++11 standard library (e.g. at [CppReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/)) list of headers. It's not that big.

Comment: Also, `boost::shared_mutex` and `boost::optional` will be standardized into C++14. I believe there is also a proposal for `boost::any`, but I am not sure.